# Этимология слова "регипс"

Tags: этимология, заимствования

Какова этимология слова ***регипс***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ре (лат.) — приставка, указывающая: 1) на повторное, возобновляемое действие (например, реконструкция); 2) на противоположное, обратное действие, противодействие (например, реэвакуация).

Гипс — порошкообразный вяжущий материал, получаемый путём термической обработки природного двухводного гипса.

Регипс (Rigips) — влагостойкий после процеса влажного формования листовой материал, тоже, что гипсокартон, но с большим содержанием пластификаторов для гутья на месте элементов скругления углов помещения, монтажа арок, сложных потолков. Подобно гипсу-порошку **восстанавливает** при взаимодействии с водой природные свойства камня: прочность, влагонепроницаемость, негорючесть.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! а вот существует версия, что это слово произошло от соединения слов гипс и Рига, что этот материал был впервые произведен на Рижской гипсовой фабрике... ничего не слышали об этом?

Comment: @  shampar  Rigips - австрийская торговая  фирма, она производит различные строительные материалы, не только гипсокартон. С другой стороны, "рынок строительных материалов России в основном переполнен продукцией четырех довольно крупных производителей гипсокартона: английская «Gyproc» (Гипрок), французская «Lafarge» (Лафарж), немецкая «Knauf» (Кнауф) и австрийская «Rigips» (Ригипс)".  Что такое Ri в названии Rigips так и не удалось найти. У Вас есть какие-нибудь ссылки на эту тему?

Comment: вот мне рассказали :) , что в немецком варианте википедии вот так написано,  что  rigips это от rigaer gips


Что в Риге в 1938 году что-то такое делали.
А потом уже после войны в Германии открыли фирму всяких стройматериалов (до сих пор работает), у них в , у них в названии есть слово rigips

Comment: В Риге действительно до недавнего времени работала фабрика гипса.

Comment: @Илона Да, в немецкой Википедии об этом сказано. Там не указан источник информации, но за неимением лучшего материала этому вполне можно доверять.

Comment: да, тем более, что в нашем рижском строительном коллежде. оказывается, это даже рассказывают на лекциях - как факт)))

Comment: Сходная с ГКЛ марка гипсофибрового листа GYPROC Glasroс Riflex F ГФЛ имеет адаптированное наименование Рифлекс ПрК (ГФЛ). Врядли оно имеет связь с производителем из Риги, но звуковым соответствием с известным словом и знаковым  префиксом, возможно, привело к такому результату. Так или иначе слово сленговое.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, "Регипс" - торговая марка гипсокартона, которая стала использоваться как имя нарицательное, что в русском язіке не редкость (от  ксерокса до памперсов).

На разных сайтах встречается упоминание "regips" в ряду других торговых названий гипсокартона (ригипс, валлборд, альчипан, плакоплатр и т. п.), используемых в разных странах).

> Panels are also known as ***gypsum board, wallboard, plasterboard*** (USA,
>   UK, Ireland, Australia), Gibraltar board or GIB wall and ***ceiling
>   linings*** (in New Zealand, trademark of Winstone Wallboards[2]), rock
>   lath,[3] ***Sheetrock*** (a trademark of USG Corporation), ***rigips, regips or
>   knauf*** (Germany and Central Europe, after the Rigips, Regips and Knauf
>   brands, respectively), **alçıpan** in Turkey, **placoplatre** (France) and
>   Pladur (Spain).

http://wikidwelling.wikia.com/wiki/Drywall

К сожалению, это информация недостоверна без уточнения, какой именно фирме принадлежит данная марка. Тем более невозможно установить этимологии самого названия фирмы или марки.  Но если с наличием "гипса" в названии еще как-то  можно согласиться, то латинская приставка "ре" была бы тут совершенно неуместна.

В отношении ригипса и других слов из этого ряда, я, пожалуй, воздержусь от комментариев. Все правдоподобно, но вряд ли достоверно.

Answer (score 0):

По подсказке автора вопроса можно найти следующую информацию в немецкой Википедии (я сделал непрофессиональный перевод ).

[В статье о гипсокартоне](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gipskarton):

> В качестве синонимов гипсовых плат в немецкоязычных странах часто
>   используется Rigips, поскольку первый гипсокартон на европейском
>   материке был изготовлен в 1938 году в Риге («Rigear gips»). Rigips —
>   это название торговой марки, ставшее обобщенным брендом.

А также в [статье о компании – производителе строительных материалов](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Gobain_Rigips):

> Название Rigips состоит из слов "Рига" и "гипс"; в Риге в 1938 году был создан
>   первый в Европе завод по производству гипсокартона.

Что касается торговой марки Регипс (или Regips), мне не удалось пока найти никакой информации о данном продукте и о его производителе. Я уверен, что если бы существовала такая торговая марка, в Интернете можно было бы найти хотя бы одну картинку с настоящей логотипом производителя (или хотя бы с названием). Могу предположить только, что в данном случае мы имеем дело со всемирным заговором неграмотных людей. Но это только частная гипотеза.